# Visual Studio variable as an array index

Tags: c++

I was wondering why visual studio is not letting me declare the variable "index" inside the brackets as an array. It worked on other IDEs. Don't mind input.txt btw

```
  int main()
{
ifstream fin("input.txt");
int alpha = 0, punct = 0;
char character;
int ascii, index;


while (fin >> character)
{
    if (isalpha(character))
    {
        alpha++;
    }
    if (ispunct(character))
    {
        punct++;
    }
    if (isalpha(character))
    {
        ascii = (int)character;
        index = ascii - 97;
        alpha[index]++;

    }
}
cout << endl;

cout << "Alpha: " << alpha << endl;
cout << "Puncts: " << punct << endl;

fin.close();




return 0;
}
```

Comment: Initialize it as `index = 0 `

Comment: Moving it to an answer then.

Answer (score 2):

You defined the variable `int alpha = 0` which is a single `int`. Later in your code you have `alpha[index]++;` which attempts to use the `int` variable `alpha` as an array. That's why you're getting the compiler error.

I'm going to guess that `ascii` was meant to be an array of individual character counts. Your code will compile with a small change; defining `ascii` as an array of `int`.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    int alpha = 0, punct = 0;
    char character;
    int ascii[26] = {}, index;

    while (fin >> character) {
        if (isalpha(character)) {
            alpha++;
        }
        if (ispunct(character)) {
            punct++;
        }
        if (isalpha(character)) {
            index = character - 97;
            ascii[index]++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Alpha: " << alpha << endl;
    cout << "Puncts: " << punct << endl;

    fin.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`C++` is a strongly "typed language" where you need to be maximally discrete about everything. When you create a new variable and don't initialize it as anything, you simply get the so called `garbage value`, which was before in that particular part in the memory. It can be anything. 
So initializing it as `index = 0` solves the problem.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem. It's true that `index` isn't initialized when it's defined but in this code it's always given a value before it's read from. The real problem is trying to use an `int` as if it were an array.

Comment: I see that but, if you look closer, `index` is never used without first giving it a value so there's no uninitialized read here. If the OP tried your suggestion they would know the code still wouldn't compile.